# Can't run gParted Live

Tags: boot, livecd, gparted, unetbootin

I prepared gParted Live on my pendrive using unetbootin. When I try to boot from that pendrive I got blikning line and nothing more. What could me wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Pendrive Linux's Universal USB tool](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/). This one actually works, while Unetbootin failed on me.